# Invalid read of Size 1 when mallocing large String

Tags: c, string, malloc

I have a unique case where I'm trying to store a 4096 character string in a struct member. However, I'm mallocing the usually amount of memory for a shorter string, but am still getting a valgrind error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct List {
    char * name;
    int grade;
    struct List * next;
};
int main(void) {
    struct List * newList;
    char * bigString;
    int i;
    bigString = malloc(sizeof(char)* 4096);

    for (i=0; i<4096; i++)
      bigString[i] = 'a';


    newList = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    newList->next = NULL;
    newList->name = malloc(strlen(bigString)+1);
    free(bigString);


    free(newList->name);
    free(newList);


    return 0;
}
```

the line:

```
newList->name = malloc(strlen(bigString)+1);
```

Returns an error `Invalid read of size 1`

But wait a second, I'm mallocing the lenght of the string, plus 1 for the null terminator, what's going on here?

In fact I even tried this:

```
newList->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(bigString) +1);
```

And heck I even tried to null terminate the string after the malloc call:

```
newList->name[strlen(bigString)] = '\0';
```

To no avail..

I'm actually beyond confused as to what I've done wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: `bigString = malloc(sizeof(char)* 4096);` -->`bigString = malloc(sizeof(char)* 4096+1); bigString[4096] = 0;`

Comment: That returns an invalid write of size 1 :/

Comment: Did you change `i<4096` ?

Comment: Yeah never mind it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bigString` itself is not null-terminated, so `strlen(bigString)` results in trying to read past the end of the space allocated for `bigString`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a `\0` at the end of `BigString`.